# How to generate the stereographic projection of a 3D model

Tags: image-processing, projections, raster-image

Given a 3D model, is there a way to [stereographically project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) it to a 2D image? In particular, I would only need a little more than half the model (the lower half) to be mapped to the plane (mapping the whole 3D model would be impossible, since the stereographic projection is infinite).

I am using Linux, if that makes any difference. Also, I would prefer to use free software.

(Note: If I could increase the viewing angle, I could do this with most any 3D viewing software, since the stereographic projection is just the view from a certain point with a wide viewing angle. In particular, I was able to get a small portion of the stereographic projection from meshlab.)

Comment: Stereographic projection implies projecting the surface of a sphere onto a plane. So unless your model is also spherical you're gonna get self-intersections on the plane. Is this what you want?

Comment: @russ It is nearly spherical (a polyhedron).

Comment: Do you need an actual stereographic projection? Or just any conformal one-to-one projection to the plane would also work. There are better approaches to map surfaces (or any topological disk) to a plane. You acn even map a topological sphere (closed surface) to the plane without seams decomposing it in two charts. Closed surface of high genus can be also mapped but would require more charts.

Comment: @MauricioCeleLopezBelon I wanted sterographic, but that works too.

Answer (score 1):

If instead of stereographic projection you can use other conformal projection. I would recommend you the "Least Squares Conformal Maps" algorithm. There are several implementations out there, including the prominent CGAL (https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_parameterization/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Using blender, you can position the camera at the north pole of the sphere you are stereographically projecting, and then set a really wide [field of view](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/camera.html#perspective). For example, I had to set my focal length to around 5 mm to get a hemisphere in the stereographic projection, but it will depend on the model, of course. Then simply render and you're done!